# How can i connect/login to OneDrive with username and password using C#?

Tags: c#, onedrive

I can connect to OneDrive from within the onedrive url using username and password.
I am trying to put together a c# app which will login in the user.
Is there some sample app which can outline the steps required ?

Comment: OneDrive clients don't authenticate with a username and password, instead you should use the official OneDrive API that's part of _Microsoft Graph_ which uses OIDC and OAuth2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/?view=odsp-graph-online

Comment: For AuthX (Authentication and Authorization) instructions, see this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/authentication?view=odsp-graph-online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this will do the job.

```
    public async Task GetTokenAsync(string tenant, string clientId, string clientSecret, string username, string password)
{
    HttpResponseMessage resp;
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token/");
         req.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
         {
            {"grant_type", "password"},
            {"client_id", clientId},
            {"client_secret", clientSecret},
            {"resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com"},
            {"username", username},
            {"password", password}
         });

         resp = await httpClient.SendAsync(req);
         string content = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         var jsonObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(content);               
         string token = jsonObj["access_token"];                
         Console.WriteLine(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume the tenant, clientId  and clientSecret need to be retrieved from the OneDrive portal ?

Comment: I'm surprised this works at all, I'd have thought there'd be an anti-XSS token rendered to the page or similar.